# Is it possible to create new object without URL?

Tags: desktop-application, facebook-opengraph

Use scenario is pretty simple: I have a desktop only application that could be connected to facebook and when user does something (watches video, listens music, shares playlist, etc) I want this app to publish a new action (for new OpenGraph protocol).

From what I've seen in FB docs, at the moment you need to send action name and URL of the page with special markup for new object. But because I have a desktop app, there's no way to do this (since there's no server).

So, the question is - can I create this object using API only? Or I will need to set up the whole server for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each object /action needs to be associated with a URL Facebook can reach to crawl the metadata (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/ ) - if your app is primarily mobile there doesn't really need to be anything AT that URL except the tags which tell Facebook about the object, but that URL does need to exist.
For example, Spotify uses URLs like this: http://open.spotify.com/track/737liXlwQnrGkVszJqVbOv
That page has the meta tags which Facebook looks at. There's no reason your app couldn't just use simple placeholder pages like that

Comment: remember - when a user on Facebook clicks on the link to that object, they'll be redirected to that URL - so as well as containing metadata Facebook can read, you need to ensure it displays some content that a user on coming from a web link would want to see.

Comment: Sorry yes, I should have been more clear about that - Spotify's pages are a good example of this

Comment: ah, okay. thanks a lot for the explanation. that's kinda sad :\

Comment: If it ain't on the web, it don't exist ;-)